# Add Button above Keyboard android

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to add a button above the default keyboard in Android and I want to reuse a lot of times.

Something like this:

[image: button above keyboard]

So, in such a case, do I need to create a new Custom keyboard OR is there a way to add this button programmatically every time i want this button above the keyboard?

Can anyone recommend the right way to go. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all...It just like a trick...Add the following code in your layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendMsgButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#FF9800"
            android:text="This button"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then dynamically show or hide this(in keyboard listener) by using hese 2 code on the right places:

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is implementing a listener to check if the keyboard is visible and toggling the visibility of the button. For the button I suggest using a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout as the parent view with the button aligned to the bottom.